# Calculating Inverse of Polynomial Rings

Tags: java, polynomial-math, inverse, ntruencrypt

I try to understand the NTRU-PKCS and wanted to implement a simple Version in Java, therefore I used a self-implemented method (extend euclid) for calculating the Inverse of a Polynomial in a Ring.

Most of the times my Algorithm works, but when I try the example from the NTRU-PKCS-Tutorial [PKCS-Tutorial](https://assets.securityinnovation.com/static/downloads/NTRU/resources/NTRU-PKCS-Tutorial.pdf) it fails and I dont know why.

The Example is:

f: -x^10+1x^9+0x^8+0x^7+1x^6+0x^5-x^4+0x^3+1x^2+1x^1-x^0
f^-1 mod 32: 30x^10+18x^9+20x^8+22x^7+16x^6+15x^5+4x^4+16x^3+6x^2+9x^1+5x^0
Ring: x^11-1

My Code is:

```
public PolynomialMod inverse(int N, int mod) {
    int loop = 0;
    PolynomialMod G = PolynomialMod.ZERO.clone();
    G.setNMod(N, mod);
    PolynomialMod newG = (PolynomialMod) PolynomialMod.ONE.clone();
    newG.setNMod(N, mod);
    int[] coeffR = { 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 };

    PolynomialMod quotient = null;
    PolynomialMod newR = this.clone();
    PolynomialMod R = this.getRing(N, mod);
    R.setNMod(N, mod);
    newR.setNMod(N, mod);

    while (!newR.equalsZero()) {
        if (DEBUG && loop != 0)
            System.out.println("loop: " + loop);
        if (DEBUG && loop == 0)
            System.out.println("========Initial Values========");
        if (DEBUG)
            System.out.println("R   : " + R);
        if (DEBUG)
            System.out.println("newR: " + newR);
        if (DEBUG)
            System.out.println("Quotient: " + quotient);
        if (DEBUG)
            System.out.println("G   : " + G);
        if (DEBUG)
            System.out.println("newG: " + newG);
        if (DEBUG && loop == 0)
            System.out.println("========Initial Values========");
        if (DEBUG)
            System.out.println("\n");

        quotient = R.div(newR)[0];
        PolynomialMod help = R.clone();
        R = newR.clone();
        PolynomialMod times = quotient.times(newR);
        times.reduceBetweenZeroAndQ();
        newR = help.sub(times);
        newR.deleteLeadingZeros();
        newR.degree = newR.values.size() - 1;
        help = G.clone();
        G = newG.clone();
        PolynomialMod times2 = quotient.times(newG);
        times2.reduceBetweenZeroAndQ();
        newG = help.sub(times2);
        loop++;

    }
    if (R.getDegree() > 0)
        throw new ArithmeticException("irreducible or multiple");

    return G.div(R)[0];
}
```

The output is like:

```
========Initial Values========
R   : [ -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ]
newR: [ -1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, -1 ]
Quotient: null
G   : [ 0 ]
newG: [ 1 ]
========Initial Values========


loop: 1
R   : [ -1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, -1 ]
newR: [ 30, 0, 2, 1, 31, 31, 1, 1, 0, 1 ]
Quotient: [ 31, 31 ]
G   : [ 1 ]
newG: [ 1, 1 ]


loop: 2
R   : [ 30, 0, 2, 1, 31, 31, 1, 1, 0, 1 ]
newR: [ 1, 31, 31, 1, 1, 0, 31, 0, 1 ]
Quotient: [ 1, 31 ]
G   : [ 1, 1 ]
newG: [ 0, 0, 1 ]


loop: 3
R   : [ 1, 31, 31, 1, 1, 0, 31, 0, 1 ]
newR: [ 30, 31, 3, 2, 30, 30, 1, 2 ]
Quotient: [ 0, 1 ]
G   : [ 0, 0, 1 ]
newG: [ 1, 1, 0, 31 ]
```

The Problem is: if I calculate R/newR now I have to find the inverse of 2 mod 32 but since the greatest common divisor of 32 and 2 is 2 not 1, there is no inverse...

Have I implemented the algorithm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved: It wasnt an euclidean ring, so I had to calculate the inverse mod 2 and then lift it to mod 32...

[how it works](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/37063/calculating-polynomial-inverse-with-extended-euclid-in-java/37329#37329)